# How do I find and get value from multi dimensional array in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Basically I have an array that looks something like

```
areaCodes = @ (
 @("310", "LA"),
 @("212", "NY"),
 @("702", "LV")
)
```

I would like to have it so that for example if I have a variable `$code = $212` Find if it is in the list, and if is, get the value associated with it.

Something like

```
if($areaCodes.contains($code))
{
 WRITE-HOST $areaCodes[1]
}
```

and this would output NY

How do I do this in powershell? Or is there are more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enumerate all arrays inside your array for this to work, for example:

```
($areaCodes | Where-Object { $_ -contains $code })[1] # => NY
```

Or using an actual loop:

```
foreach($array in $areaCodes) {
    if($array -contains $code) {
        $array[1]
        break
    }
}
```

But taking a step back, a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) seems a lot more appropriate for your use case:

```
$code = 212
$areaCodes = @{
    310 = "LA"
    212 = "NY"
    702 = "LV"
}

$areaCodes[$code] # => NY
```

Comment: Thanks for the hash table! I did not know these existed. It is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: @Pa3k.m my pleasure :) a hashtable is what you may know as a dictionary in other languages (such as Python for example)

Comment: Another question - Would it be possible to put arrays inside a hash table?

Comment: @Pa3k.m of course

Comment: How do I do it? Because everytime I put an array as a Hash Table value, it ends up being combined into 1

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like I was just having problems with datatypes